# How to read doubles from .txt file into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read doubles from a file that contains 100,000 doubles, arranged in lines of two doubles each separated by a space. Like this:

```
2.54343 5.67478
1.23414 5.43245
7.64748 4.25536
...
```

My code so far:

```
Scanner numFile = new Scanner(new File("input100K.txt").getAbsolutePath());
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
while (numFile.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = numFile.nextLine();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
    sc.useDelimiter(" ");
    while(sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        list.add(sc.nextDouble());
    }
    sc.close();
}
numFile.close();
System.out.println(list);
}
```

After this code runs, it prints to the console and empty ArrayList `[]`, and I can't figure out why.

Removing the `getAbsolutePath()` from the file gives me this line:

```
Scanner numFile = new Scanner(new File("input100K.txt"));
```

but when I run the program, it is giving me a FileNotFoundException. I know the file exists, I can see it and open it.

`input100K.txt` is located in the src package folder along with the program. is there somewhere specific where the file must be for this to work?

**EDIT**: As **Evgeniy Dorofeev** pointed out, the file needs to be in the project folder (parent of src folder) for the program to find it.

Comment: Looks like you're not finding the expected file. Try putting the absolute path of your file or printing it before reading it to check if it exists.

Comment: I'd definitely add a check in the beginning to make sure the file exists and is readable, it could very well be like @LuiggiMendoza said, that it's not finding the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create Scanner like this `new Scanner(new File("input100K.txt").getAbsolutePath())`; you are scanning file path as input not file itself. Do it this way `new Scanner(new File("input100K.txt"));`

Comment: Doing it this way, I'm now getting a `FileNotFoundException`. Is there a specific place that the file should be on my computer? right now, it is in my src package folder that also contains the program.

Comment: Try to  place it in project folder

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `split()` method on the line you just have read, then parsing each part to a `double`. Note that it's not necessary to create two `Scanner`s:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input100K.txt"));
sc.useDelimiter(" ");
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] parts = sc.nextLine().split(" "); // split each line by " "
    for (String s : parts) {
        list.add(Double.parseDouble(s)); // parse to double
    }
}
sc.close();

System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the line

```
Scanner numFile = new Scanner(new File("input100K.txt").getAbsolutePath());
```

with

```
Scanner numFile = new Scanner(new File("input100K.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample program :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/home/visruthcv/inputfile.txt"));
        while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {

            double value = scanner.nextDouble();

            System.out.println(value);

            doubleList.add(value);

        }
        /*
         * for test print
         */
        for (Double eachValue : doubleList) {
            System.out.println(eachValue);
        }

    }
```